# Can I use BeanValidation on annotations themselves?

Tags: java, annotations, bean-validation, annotation-processing

I'm working on an annotation processor and became curious.

Does it make any sense to annotate like this and validate within the annotation processor?

```java
@Retention(value = RUNTIME)
@Target(value = {FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER})
public @interface BitProperty {

    @Min(1)
    @Max(31)
    int scale() default 31;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not even sure that this supposed to do? What would your expectation be? When the annotation processor runs you want that validation occurs and annotations with invalid parameter values (eg `scale > 31`) throw a constraint violation exception which in turn would abort the annotation processing?

The biggest problem here is that an annotation processor does not deal with `Annotation` instances, but rather with `AnnotationMirrow` and other classes within the `javax.lang.model.element` package. Bean Validation and Hibernate Validator are not designed to work with this reflective API. So, not, it won't work.